# tag synonyms suggestions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

A couple of tag synonym suggestions:

[out-of-memory](/questions/tagged/out-of-memory) == [outofmemoryerror](/questions/tagged/outofmemoryerror)

[particle-swarm](/questions/tagged/particle-swarm) == [pso](/questions/tagged/pso)

[sound](/questions/tagged/sound) == [sounds](/questions/tagged/sounds)

On another note, I can't remember how many times I wanted to suggest tag synonyms just to be informed that I need "5 votes in this tag"... I wish there was a new privilege we can earn to "suggest tag synonyms" no matter what. I mean we can create new tags, but we can't suggest synonyms!

Comment: While we're at it: [tag:crc32] == [tag:crc16] == [tag:crc]?

Comment: @Patashu: sure. unfortunately my suggestions are yet to be applied :)

Comment: [sound] and [sounds] should be automatically mapped to one of them.

Comment: @Luke: it is not. As of now [sound] became synonym for [audio], but [sounds] is still separate

Answer (score 1):

I agree it would be good to be able to suggest e.g. that [undefined-reference](/questions/tagged/undefined-reference) and [undefined-symbol](/questions/tagged/undefined-symbol) are synonyms, and maybe [unresolved-external](/questions/tagged/unresolved-external), even though I don't have enough answers on them to do so.

> [out-of-memory](/questions/tagged/out-of-memory) == [outofmemoryerror](/questions/tagged/outofmemoryerror)

Are they really the same?  The first is a generic error that can arise in many environments, the second is the Java `OutOfMemoryError` exception class, used to report out-of-memory conditions.  (I'm genuinely interested in the answer to this, as I've just been trying to edit the [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow), [stackoverflowerror](/questions/tagged/stackoverflowerror) and [stackoverflowexception](/questions/tagged/stackoverflowexception) tag wikis to say the latter two are the Java and .NET exception classes used to indicate the former, but it got rejected for being incorrect and "just not true".)

Comment: the current description may be Java specific, but browsing through the list of questions you can see a few other languages. After all, the concept of out-of-memory errors is language agnostic. Perhaps the tag wiki needs to be updated as such.. The way I see it if the same concept overlaps different languages, I'd rather have one generic tag to cover them all, with the different variations pointing to it as synonyms. But thats my opinion :)

Comment: I wish they introduced hierarchies to tags (with tags allowed to be listed under multiple parents)