# Can high rep users suggest tag synonyms?

Tags: support, tags, privileges, tag-synonyms, alias

I see that tag synonyms (aliases) [exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14365/tag-aliases-synonyms), however I can't seem to figure out how they actually get created.

There's at least one question on meta where synonyms are [proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142612/tag-synonyms-suggestions).  Is that something that only moderators can do, or can other users do that sort of thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you go to a tag there is a link for synonyms.

[image]

When this link is clicked, you will see the following message:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Right below this message you will be able to suggest the synonym if you meet the requirements.

[image]

Comment: no one shall forget the free hand circle ^_^

Comment: I won't.  Thanks, that's perfect.

Comment: @mgilson - hehe, wasn't refered to you. I was quoting a common meta meme. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/171199) for reference ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can. See this page from the privilege section: [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). Since the requirement is high, low rep user usually just post a request on meta so that others may do the work.

You also have the link in your privilege screen.

[image]

Click [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges) to check.

Edit: forgot the free-hand circle ^_^'

Comment: Unfortunately 2500 rep is the easy part of the requirement, the hard part is having 5 upvotes on the exact tag. Being 35,000 or so existing tags.